# Backbone.Model has no method 'extend'

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

After loading Backbone, creating new model instances with:

```
var foo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Fails with the following error:

```
    object (function details here) has no method 'extend'
```

Have solved this, but posting here to be nice and act as a reference to myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load underscore.js before backbone - see https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/711

Comment: As a matter of habit unless you're using something like LABjs you should always list any library marked as a dependency before said library. Most libraries won't fail to load, but will cause I intended side effects.